# SQL Server loop for changing multiple values of different users

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the next table:

[image]

Supposing these users are sort in descending order based on their inserted date.

Now, what I want to do, is to change their sorting numbers in that way that for each user, the sorting number has to start from 1 up to the number of appearances of each user. The result should look something like:

[image]

Can someone provide me some clues of how to do it in sql server ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) ranking function to calculate a row's rank given a partition and order.

In this case, you want to calculate row numbers for each user `PARTITION BY User_ID`. The desired output shows that ordering by ID is enough `ORDER BY ID`.

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    User_ID, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Id) AS Sort_Number
FROM MyTable
```

There are other ranking functions you can use, eg RANK, DENSE_RANK to calculate a rank according to a score, or NTILE to calculate percentiles for each row.

You can also use the `OVER` clause with aggragets to create running totals or moving averages, eg `SUM(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Id)` will create a running total of the Id values for each user.

Answer (score 0):

use ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY User_Id

```
SELECT
    Id,
    [User_Id],
    Sort_Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User_Id] 
                              ORDER BY [User_Id],[CreatedDate] DESC)
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ranking function `row_number()`

```
select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by User_id order by user_id, date desc) 
from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
,user_id
,row_number() over(partition by user_id order by user_id) as sort_number 
from table
```