# SQL Qry required to get a comma separated string from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

In my database there is a table with values below

image attached[image]

In need a qry to get the result like this

[image]

Comment: use stuff in your query

Comment: @SandipPatel STUFF doesn't perform string aggregation

Comment: The artible [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) describes and compares all of the available methods to concatenate strings. This question has been asked many times before and all answers use it as a reference

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question has one flaw actually (read the comments). It will not re-escape xml entities (in case your string includes characters such as `<, > or &`. The solution is `TYPE` in connection with `.value()`. So the here given answer by Sandip Patel seems to be a good fit...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You are right, that quesitons should not be answered again and again. But: In many cases older questions do not show the best / up-to-date approach. I've closed this as duplicate, then tool a closer look at the accepted answer in the linked question. Just closing duplicate questions can lead to sub-optimal answers....

Comment: @Panagiotis: look at your answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620661/6606630 (this also answerd so many time, even you answer), can i know why?

Comment: @SandipPatel because you posted the *wrong* explanation and code you found somewhere else without attribution or even understanding what it does. Because such things make it *harder* to find answers. Because in the end it may be faster to post a quick answer than search for the duplicate.

Comment: I already told you I have write code own. nice thing your code naturally and mine was copy paste: good mate nice thinking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(SIDS INT,VALUE VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TAB

SELECT 1,'ASC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'ASC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'ASC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'SDF'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'SFD'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'ERF'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'ERF1'


SELECT T1.SIDS,VALUE = STUFF((SELECT ','+T2.VALUE FROM @TAB T2 WHERE T1.SIDS = T2.SIDS FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM @TAB T1
GROUP BY T1.SIDS
```

OUTPUT

```
SIDS    VALUE
1   ASC,ASC,ASC
2   SDF,SFD
3   ERF,ERF1
```

Comment: Same as the other answer, no explanation, the same thing has been answered with full explanations dozens of times. Adding *another* answer, especially without explanation, doesn't help anyone. It actually makes it HARDER for the next person to find the solution

Comment: hmmm.....may be :)

Answer (score 1):

Use XML query as below;

```
DECLARE @tblQuestion AS Table
(
    SID INT,
    Value VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(1,'stu')
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(1,'vtu')
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(1,'ztu')
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(2,'stu')
INSERT INTO @tblQuestion VALUES(2,'vtu')

select distinct t.SID,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.Value
         from @tblQuestion t1
         where t.SID = t1.SID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') Value
from @tblQuestion t;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It's not *STUFF* that aggregates the strings. It's the XML query that does so. There are a lot of ways to perform string aggregation and that's only one of them

Comment: yes, we can also achieve with `SUBSTRING`

Comment: Besides, this question has been answered dozens of times already. Answering the same thing again just adds noise

Comment: Ummm, you think `SUBSTRING()` can ***aggregate***???

Comment: @SandipPatel you copied this query either from another SO query or a blog post. Read them to understand *what* they do and the potential issues. STUFF and SUBSTRING only remove the trailing comma. This query will encode characters that can't appear inside XML strings, like `<` and `&`

Comment: I haven't copy I know STUFF use. If I don't know use I don't reply as comment on question, see my first comment

Comment: @SandipPatel perhaps you should check the *source* for that code [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation). If STUFF, REPLACE or SUBSTRING did what you claim, why do you need the XML query?

Comment: Thanks mate for your valuable input.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right about the XML encoding, but - in the code above - the usage of `TYPE` and `.value()` will re-escape all entities.

Comment: Be polite like @Shnugo, He has mention same thing but in diff manner.